# Limitations of Assumptions

Tags: assumptions

Why don't

```
Simplify[x[2, 1] < x[1, 3], 
         Assumptions -> {x[a_, b_] > x[c_, d_] /; a > b && c < d}]
```

or

```
Simplify[x[2, 1] < x[1, 3], 
         Assumptions -> {\[Not] (x[a_, b_] <= x[c_, d_]) /; a > b && c < d}]
```

return False?

While imposing the weaker assumption

```
Simplify[x[2, 1] < x[1, 3], 
         Assumptions -> {\[Not] (x[a_, b_] < x[c_, d_]) /; a > b && c < d}]
```

does return False?

Interestingly,

```
Simplify[x[2, 1] <= x[1, 3], 
         Assumptions -> {(x[a_, b_] > x[c_, d_]) /;a > b && c < d}]
```

does return False. FullSimplify behaves the same way. Is there a logic issue?

Does this mean that when working with Assumptions, we must explicitly write all the options? Is there a better approach than

```
Simplify[x[2, 1] < x[1, 3], 
 Assumptions -> {(x[a_, b_] >  x[c_, d_])/;a > b && c < d,
          \[Not] (x[a_, b_] <  x[c_, d_])/;a > b && c < d, 
          \[Not] (x[a_, b_] <= x[c_, d_])/;a > b && c < d}]
```

To use Reduce would require expanding the assumed inequalities for all the many possible values of a, b, c and d, no? That seems impractical.